# Error with form submitting

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I am trying to submit a html form to a php file, which sends a mail. I tryied before woth ajax and it behaved very strange, when i changed to pure html & php it also behaved strange.
So i have this form:

```
<form id="comandaform" action="send.php" method="post">
        <div class="ordercol">
            <label for="nume">Nume companie</label>
            <input type="text" id="nume" name="nume" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
            <label for="tel">Telefon (te sunam noi!)</label>
            <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" />
        </div>
        <div class="ordercol">
            <label for="detalii">Detalii despre domeniul tau de activitate</label>
            <textarea name="detalii" id="detalii"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="trimite"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

The PHP script that handles this is:

```
<?php

$nume = $_POST["nume"];
$mail = $_POST["email"];
$tel = $_POST["tel"];
$det = $_POST["detalii"];
$mess = "";

if(isset($nume)&&isset($mail)&&isset($tel)&&isset($det))
{
$to      = 'mail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Comanda Site100';
$message = 'Nume companie:  '.$nume.'\n'.
    'Telefon: '. $tel.'\n'.
    'E-mail: '. $mail.'\n'.

'Detalii:\n'.
$det;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message))
{
    echo "succes";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}
}else{
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

When i try to submit, the browser will not find the `send.php` file. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `<input type="submit" id="submit" value="trimite" name="submit"/>`

you forgot write `name` element

Comment: Can you reach the send.php by typing the url in you browser? And, is the send.php file in the same folder as your other php file?

Comment: are they both in the same dir? do you have unix file system? you know, it's case sensetive to filenames.

Comment: Yes i have the send.php in the same dir. I don't think it's unix file system, anyway the file is named send.php. And yes i can reach the send.php by typing the url in my browser.

Comment: Also in Chrome i get this error: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually get a file not found error?

add a line write at the top of your send.php

something like:

echo 'processing form...';

just so you can see that the page is loading properly.

then try just loading it manually

eg.

if you form is at

http://www.mydomain.com/form.html

then try loading send.php by typing

http://www.mydomain.com/send.php

make sure it loads ok.

you could also change all the $_POST to $_REQUEST then you can test it with a query string

eg.

http://www.mydomain.com/send.php?nume=bob

that should move you in the right direction towards finding your problem... if not post back letting us know what happened with the above.

Comment: Good general troubleshooting tips for PHP files!

Comment: I tried what you said. It helped me find what is causing the error: the `mail()` function call.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed about your code right away.

First, if your browser is not finding `send.php`, that strongly indicates that you have a pathing error. You're either missing a subfolder in your HTML action pathing, or the file is located somplace other than where you expect it to be.

Second, even if you do find the form, it will likely kick out an error. If any of those fields are blank, you will get an error `unidentified index call` when trying to assign the $_POST key to a local variable. Next, when you check to see if the variable is set, well, of course they are, after all, you just set them. They will have a value of undefined, however, if any of the fields of the form are left blank.

```
//Use an inline check when assigning the form field values
$nume = isset($_POST["nume"]) ? $_POST["nume"] : '';
```

Then, when it comes to checking for completeness...

```
//Check for empty values
if (!empty($nume) && !empty($mail) && !empty($tel) && !empty($det)){
// Etc...
```